# Подвисает проверка синтаксиса в TypeScript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Подскажите, почему может подвисать проверка синтаксиса в visual studio code.

Т.е я правлю то, на что он указал, но VSC продолжает ругаться на это место.

Затем я делаю намеренные ошибки и он на них не реагирует.

Когда я перезапускаю VSC, то все снова работает

Comment: не по теме, но Вы пробовали jetbrains webstorm? =)

Comment: Так , вроде, для ангуляра самое лучшее это VS Code, если верить интернетам.

Comment: сколько она весит и устанавливается, если не секрет?

Comment: 50 мб. Устанавливается шустро.

Comment: ну что я могу сказать, поковыряйте логи =)